# NextJS Dynamic Link for Page & Subpage

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-link

Using NextJS I Have Dynamic Pages and Dynamic SubPages.

Here is Folders/Files :

```
pages
├── [Formation]
├── index.js
│   ├── [SubPage].js
```

In `index.js` (Formation Page), I Create Links :

```js
<Link href={`[Formations]/[SubPage]`} as={`${Title}/${item}`}>{item}</Link>
<Link href="ReactJS/Udemy">Udemy</Link>
```

The First One is what I use to navigate to Subpage. But It's not Working the way it should. Navigation is correct, but It Reload the entire page and my Layout in `_app.js`

The Second is a Test, and it's working, it does not reload the Layout

Both Create the same `<a>` Tag

Do you know Why the first one isn't working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are following the old way to handle dynamic route in `NextJs`. Since the `as` prop is a simple decorator and `href` the path your are trying to navigate to, consider doing:

```js
<Link href={`${Title}/${item}`}>{item}</Link>
```

Comment: That was so simple... Thanks dude, it's working. Sorry to have disturbed you for this. When I first Tried this, I had an error so thought this was not the solution, and didn't retried